# Under Ubuntu, how do I get a big endian cross compile to ARM working?

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-platform, endianness

I downloaded and installed the lintian ARM toolchain and I can get a successful little endian compile (and link).  I can use the -mbig-endian argument and I get through the compile phases, but then fail in the link phase.  I assume this is because the libraries were NOT built as big endian.  Am I wrong?  Are big-endian libraries available?  If I have to build the libraries myself, what's the easiest way for me to get that done?

Comment: 1) why big vs little 2) it is painful 3) there are lots of examples out there for building cross tools and libraries.  the mentor graphics, formerly code sourcery toolchain might already work for you, they have a free lite version you can try.  and they used to at least provide their gnu mods and build instructions, not sure if they do that anymore.  at the end of the day it is better in every way to run the native (in this case little) endian for a particular processor.  xscale folks will tell you how much of a PITA it was to deal with big endian arm...

Comment: I would think it obvious, but yes, you need big-endian versions of anything you want to link big-endian code with. Including standard libraries. Best just get a specific big-endian toolchain (usually `armeb-` prefix for modern ones) - I tend towards [the Linaro builds](https://releases.linaro.org/15.02/components/toolchain/binaries) myself.